# How to run a script 4000 time for files names from 1 to 4000 in order?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, automation

I have 4000 file named from 1 to 4000 inclusive the 1 and the 4000.

I wrote the below command which I want to run the script I wrote 4000 time for all the files from 1 to 4000, so I wrote:

```
    for i in {1..4000}; do pymol -c script.pml; done
```

The problem is that, the numbers itself in the script need to be changed every time, my script is as below:

```
    load 1.pdb 

    remove resname GRM

    color green, resname G8LE

    load 0.pdb 

    color grey40, resname GRM

    rotate x, -45

    show spheres

    save 1.png
```

I need to replace the number 1 (in the first line after load and in the last line after save) to be replaced with all the numbers from 1 to 4000. so that in each time the next file is loaded and processed then saved with its appropriate number and so on.

Can you please guide me what should I change in my script and/or in my terminal to achieve that ?

Thanks,
Mohamed

Comment: It looks like pymol scripts can access an `argv` as described here [pymolwiki: Scripting FAQs](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Scripting_FAQs)

Comment: If you are using VMD, then you can loop from 1 to 4000 and do `mol load pdb $i.pdb` and at last do `mol delete all` to remove the loaded ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be best to have an argv if possible. I don't know if pml scripts can be given an argument from the terminal. Else you can use this hack to change the pml script from bash/terminal or from .sh script where you are running this. Which will change the pml script accordingly before you run it.

```
for i in {1..40000}
do
    echo Evaluating for i = $i

    # change the script 
    sed -i "s/.*load.*/load $i.pdb;/g" test.pml # Change the text inside the file
    sed -i "s/.*save.*/save $i.png;/g" test.pml # Change the text inside the file

    # <code to run the pml file>

done
```

Let me know if this helped :)

Edit after comment:

To differentiate between load commands put and extra space iniitally in the first line of pml script and use this.

```
sed -i "s/.*load  .*/load  $i.pdb;/g" test.pml # Change the text inside the file
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for your help, it worked, but there is a small problem. The script you wrote change  all the load .pdb commands. I need to change the load 1.pdb in the first line only while the load 0.pdb in the third line need to be fixed in all the runs. Is there any modification could be done to make the change happens only to the load .pdb in the first line ?

Comment: yes, you just have to distinguish between the load commands. You can just simply add and extra space between "load  1.pdb" (2 spaces) and search by "load  " also while writing keep 2 spaces. Or you can make any other difference.

Comment: I have tried to add the space, however now both the load command didn't recognize the script. I have uploaded my scripts and all my file in the  below link. Can you please check that I have applied your space suggestion in my script correctly. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17bt7dpa1HQj_89GCaKY46lUoqttNjWCc?usp=sharing

Comment: You haven't added an extra space between 'load' and '1.pdb'  in the pml script (Total 2 spaces).
Do this for only the first line (Just for distinguishing)
Do that and it will work.